Apple Script - Variable Not Defined Error
I'm not that familiar with Apple Script.  I am wanting to setup a crontab to automagically lower the volume at night and such..  I can't find much info on this.  Is there a manual (PDF) on osascript somewhere?
error "The variable volArg is not defined." number -2753 from "volArg"
. . for . .
on run argv
    set volArg to (item 1 of argv)
    if volArg is less than 0 then set volArg to 0
    if volArg is greater than 16 then set volArg to 16
    set volume output volume volArg / 16 * 100
end run

I tried using 'global', 'property', etc.. it gives the same error.
simpler version that works..
on run argv
    set volume output volume (item 1 of argv) / 16 * 100
end run

crontab - example usage..
~/bin » crontab -l                                                                                                      
SHELL=/bin/bash

00 22 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 3)
00 23 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 2)
00 06 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 3)
00 07 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 4)
# TEST 05 15 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 0)

FINAL VERSION:
on run argv
    set volArg to (item 1 of argv) as number
    if volArg is less than 0 then set volArg to 0
    if volArg is greater than 16 then set volArg to 16
    set volume output volume volArg / 16 * 100
end run


How are you running the script? I suspect the problem is that there's nothing in item 1 of argv.

Shouldn't you use volArg in the set volume output line? Otherwise, what was the point of setting it and then restricting it to 0-16?

Ahhh.. thanks!   I didn't get that far.  I wasn't getting past the error.  I have a simpler version that works; but I wanted to bounds check the input.
crontab:

00 22 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 3)
00 23 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 2)
00 06 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 3)
00 07 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 4)
# TEST 05 15 * * * (cd $HOME/bin; osascript setvol.scpt 0)```

simple version..
```on run argv
 set volume output volume (item 1 of argv) / 16 * 100
end run```

I'm not sure it's related to this error, but you need to convert volArg to a number: set volArg to (item 1 of argv) as number

I put more info in the description.  Using "as number" results in a different error - "No result was returned from some part of this expression."

sorry.. that was a runtime error - not a compile error.  It is working!
Thanks!

Even without as number I couldn't reproduce the original error.

If I leave out the volume argument to the script, I get Can’t get item 1 of {}. (-1728)

Maybe, I was seeing a runtime error instead of a compile error.  I'm not that famialr with the Script Editor tool.

I didn't use script editor, I just put the code in a text file and ran it with osascript.

Your original error is a runtime error.
